# Using Custom Regions in Excel 3D Maps

Tags: excel, microsoft-power-map-excel

I am trying to use Custom regions (other than country, province or city boundaries - see picture below) to display data from Excel sheet on map using Excel 3D Maps (Excel 2016). I always successfully import small size (3 regions) SHP or KML file (I tried both). However, I cannot find how to use these imported custom region to display my data on the excel sheet.

[image]

I tried to google the answer in many forums, but mostly they refer to this link - https://docs.com/james-marshall/6909/custom-regions-walkthrough which is not working any longer.
Do you know how can I used imported custom regions to display my data in Excel 3D Maps?

Comment: Check out this link: https://sway.com/H7uaa8hs8betQKoJ It helped me with some of the questions on custom regions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141019)